# systemd .slice unit to limit a service to a specific interface/network classifier

Tags: systemd, cgroups, systemd-networkd

Running on CentOS 7 [systemd ~243 & cgroup v1], I would like to limit a service to one specific network interface.

The target machine has multiple physical network interfaces.
The service is supposed to ideally see and use only one specific network interface.

Can I define a .slice unit or similar to constrain the corresponding .service unit to the network interface / network classifier cgroup?